# Jquery clickable resize animation. Maximizing div over others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I can't come up with solution to my problem. 
  So I've got cool idea to make fancy looking user panel but can't figure out how to
  make jquery work right ;). Here's the thing:

```
html:
<div id="content">
<div id="containerleft">
<div id="box1" class="box"></div>
<div id="box2" class="box"></div>
<div id="box3" class="box"></div>
<div id="box4" class="box"></div>
<div id="box5" class="box"></div>
<div id="box6" class="box"></div>
</div>
</div>

JS:
$(".box").click(function(){
$(this).css({'position' : 'absolute'}).animate({
                width: '100%', 
                height : '100%'},300);
                          });
```

Here is how it work with css: 
  http://jsfiddle.net/85mJN/1/

What I'm trying to achieve is resize div from his position, to size of parent div, growing effect I would call.
  As you can see, after .click div is moving to the left top corner, and then its fiting to parent, also its ruing whole thing by moving other guys. I've tried to mess around with .css('z-index': '999') for animated div, but that was a miss. Main goal is to expand div from his original position, above other div's, without moving them.

~ sandman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".box").click(function(){

    var clone = $(this).clone().addClass('active');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var pos = $(this).position();

    $(this).append(clone);

    clone.css({'position' : 'absolute', left: pos.left + 'px', top: pos.top + 'px'}).animate({
        width: '100%', 
        height : '100%',
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    },300);


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85mJN/3/

Note that your box element should have static position so the appended box absolute position will be wrapped from the container.

UPDATE:

Added close on click while a box is active.

http://jsfiddle.net/85mJN/4/

ALSO i still think the best way to use CSS3 transition with toggleClass. It requires less code, it's much failsafe and it's smoother when your using complex divs as it's hardware accelerated. I would not worry about older browser, they won't animate but show the big box...

Comment: This is what I was looking for ;) A whole new perspective, gotta figure it out and make some additional stuff ;) like going back from that maximizing. Thx man.

Comment: Great skills. Any tuts to become more familiar with it ?

Comment: These are pretty specific things which you need to learn on your own i think. Also i've updated again...

Answer (score 0):

The movement shown in your example is a product of removing the clicked on div from the flow and then the other divs readjusting since they are floated.

A simple solution is to make the `#containerleft{ overflow:hidden; ... }`

However if that doesn't satisfy your needs making a clone works as well:

```
$('#containerleft').on("click", ".box", function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    console.log($this.css('position'));    
    if($this.css('position') === 'absolute'){ 
        $this.animate({width:'0px',height:'0px'},300);
        //$this.remove();
    }
    else {
        $this.clone().appendTo($this.parent()).css({'position' : 'absolute'}).animate({
                    width: '100%', 
                    height : '100%'},300);
    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e4NG5/2/