# Expanding a div (that has a hover flipping effect) on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an action to a clicked div that only appears when hovered (it's the "back side" of a flipping div, which is orange in the example below).

The action I'm trying to trigger is expanding the orange div so it covers all the other divs.

This is the code I'm having an issue with: http://jsfiddle.net/y892fqq1/2/

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.front,
.back,
.flip,
.flip-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
.flip-container:hover .flip,
.flip-container.hover .flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip {
  transition: 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background-color: purple;
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back" onclick="expand()"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back" onclick="expand()"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back" onclick="expand()"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back" onclick="expand()"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

(Sorry for the long lines of codes!)

Here's a post I found that fits the most to my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489601 (shortcut to code: http://jsfiddle.net/85mJN/4/), but when I try that, it doesn't seem to work ...

Does anyone have any idea how I could proceed?

Many thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Got this almost working, can't get the z-index to go above though. http://jsfiddle.net/wquauyvg/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about adding a class on click, which will style the rotating thing accordingly?

```js
$(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){ 
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    });
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
}
.expanded{
    transition: 0s  !important;
    width:200px !important;
    height:200px !important;
    z-index:10 !important;
    position:absolute !important;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
table {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.front, .back, .flip, .flip-container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
.flip-container:not(.expanded):hover .flip, .flip-container.hover .flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip {
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front, .back {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background-color:purple;
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="flip-container">
          <div class="flip">
            <div class="front"></div>
            <div class="back"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, that fixed my issue!
And here are some edits I added to enhance the result, in case someone else reads this post:

.expanded{
    transition: 1s  !important;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}